# BRUNO - Share environment variables between collections

Tags: bruno

Is there a way to share environment variables between collections? It seems that an environment belongs to one specific collection and not global as in Postman.

I'm using Bruno v1.9.0

Thanks

Comment: I have not seen a way to do what you ask thus far. I think the reason is that Bruno is designed to work locally, with a collection being the highest level of aggregation. Therefore, sharing env variable across collections is not a part of their design approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like global variables as far as i know, but if you are working on linux you can use shared folders, to share one of the environment folders with the other collections

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).